# Extracting date field

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need to pull the month field from the first table and I would like the results to look like the second table.

I know to use  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM BEGIN_DATE) to get the month but I'm unsure how to show all of the date fields. Any ideas? Using Oracle SQL.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm unsure how to ..." Does `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM BEGIN_DATE)` work or not?

Comment: I'm not sure whether END_DATE is correct or not; is it really 2199? It appears that you'd want to create as many rows (in the second table) as there are months between BEGIN_DATE and END_DATE, but - if years differ that much, it is unclear what you really want to do.

Comment: How would I extract all the months from person 654 when it only shows 9/1 and 10/31? Yes the end date really is 2199 for year. The year is that to show they are still active.

Comment: I don't understand what do you call "all months" for person 654. There are 1st of September and 31st of October. So, how to get months 9, 10, 11, 12, 1 from those values? What's the algorithm to be used?

Comment: If I'm running today how would I get all of those months?

Comment: So, for each `person_id`, you must show months from the `begin_date` for that person, through the current month? (1 since we are in January 2018?) What do you want shown for someone with `begin_date` in August 2015? The month number 9 will show three times - for 2015, 2016 and 2017. Are you 100% sure that the "month" column should show just a number, and not something like "SEP-2015", "SEP-2016" etc.? Or perhaps 9-2015, 10-2015, 11-2015 so that the output does not depend on language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do this. Note that I changed the column name from `Month` to `mth` ("month" is an Oracle keyword, it shouldn't be used as a table or column name). I also show the full month description (that is, including the year), so that there is no confusion when you have the same month (September for example) for the same `person_id` more than once. You can change that to show just the month by adjusting the format model in `TO_CHAR`, but that doesn't make much sense to me.

The test data is in the WITH clause which is NOT part of the SQL query; remove it, and use the actual table name in the SELECT query (instead of the made-up name I created in the WITH clause).

```
with
  inputs ( person_id, begin_date, end_date ) as (
    select 123, date '2017-11-01', date '2199-12-31' from dual union all
    select 654, date '2017-09-01', date '2017-10-31' from dual union all
    select 789, date '2017-12-01', date '2199-12-31' from dual
  )
select     person_id,
           to_char(add_months(trunc(begin_date, 'mm'), level - 1), 'mm-yyyy') as mth,
           case when add_months(trunc(begin_date, 'mm'), level - 1) <= end_date
                then 'Y' else 'N' end as yn
from       inputs
connect by add_months(trunc(begin_date, 'mm'), level - 1) <= sysdate
       and prior person_id = person_id
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
order by   person_id, level
;

 PERSON_ID MTH     YN
---------- ------- --
       123 11-2017 Y
       123 12-2017 Y
       123 01-2018 Y
       654 09-2017 Y
       654 10-2017 Y
       654 11-2017 N
       654 12-2017 N
       654 01-2018 N
       789 12-2017 Y
       789 01-2018 Y

 10 rows selected
```

One more thing - in the sample data, your `begin_date` is always the beginning of a month. If this is guaranteed, then you could simplify the code - there would be no need for `trunc( ...,  'mm')`  -  but I would still not change it; you don't know if this special property of the column will continue into the future, and if it ever changes, you will be glad the code addresses it already.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally understood what you want; it is SYSDATE you're running the query on. Based on it, you want to get all months that are between BEGIN_DATE and SYSDATE, for each PERSON_ID.

If that's so, here you go:

```
SQL> with test (person_id, begin_date) as
  2    (select 123, date '2017-11-01' from dual union
  3     select 654, date '2017-09-01' from dual
  4    )
  5  select person_id,
  6    to_char(add_months(trunc(begin_date, 'mm'), column_value - 1), 'mm') mon
  7  from test,
  8       table(cast(multiset
  9         (select level lvl from dual
 10          connect by level <= round(months_Between (sysdate, begin_date)) + 1)
 11          as sys.odcinumberlist))
 12  order by 1, 2;

 PERSON_ID MO
---------- --
       123 01
       123 11
       123 12
       654 01
       654 09
       654 10
       654 11
       654 12

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on mathguy's answer:

```
SELECT 
    person_id
  , TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(begin_date, LEVEL-1), 'mm') m
  , TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(begin_date, LEVEL-1), 'yyyy') y
  , CASE WHEN ADD_MONTHS(begin_date, LEVEL-1) BETWEEN begin_date and end_date THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS yn
FROM
    person_table
CONNECT BY
    LEVEL <= MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MON'), TRUNC(begin_date, 'MON')) + 1
    AND prior person_id = person_id
    AND prior sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    person_id, y, m;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f666d/62) for reference.